# Sort ADO Recordset Fields based on Custom Order

Tags: excel, vba, ado, recordset, custom-sort

I have created an ADO Recordset from a Range of a Worksheet as shown below that I want to custom sort on `Groups` field, Then `Type` field. The Sort Order should be such that, the values of `Groups` column should be arranged in a custom order as given in another worksheet range column `Status1` AND the values of `Type` column should be arranged in a custom order as given in another worksheet range column `Status2` for e.g. :

```
+====+===========+================+
|    |     A     |       B        |
+====+===========+================+
| 1  | Type      | Groups         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 2  | Restage 2 | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 3  | Restage 3 | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 4  | Restage 1 | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 5  | Current   | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 6  | Restage 1 | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 7  | Current   | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 8  | Restage 2 | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 9  | Restage 3 | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 10 | Restage 3 | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 11 | Restage 1 | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 12 | Restage 2 | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 13 | Current   | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 14 | Current   | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 15 | Restage 1 | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 16 | Restage 3 | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 17 | Restage 2 | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 18 | Current   | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 19 | Restage 3 | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 20 | Restage 2 | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 21 | Restage 1 | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 22 | Restage 2 | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 23 | Restage 1 | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 24 | Current   | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 25 | Restage 3 | Buyers         |
+====+===========+================+
```

to like this:

```
+====+===========+================+
|    |     A     |       B        |
+====+===========+================+
| 1  | Type      | Groups         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 2  | Current   | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 3  | Restage 1 | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 4  | Restage 2 | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 5  | Restage 3 | GP             |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 6  | Current   | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 7  | Restage 1 | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 8  | Restage 2 | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 9  | Restage 3 | Buyers         |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 10 | Current   | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 11 | Restage 1 | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 12 | Restage 2 | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 13 | Restage 3 | Non Buyers     |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 14 | Current   | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 15 | Restage 1 | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 16 | Restage 2 | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 17 | Restage 3 | Target Group 2 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 18 | Current   | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 19 | Restage 1 | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 20 | Restage 2 | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 21 | Restage 3 | Target Group 4 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 22 | Current   | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 23 | Restage 1 | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 24 | Restage 2 | Target Group 6 |
+----+-----------+----------------+
| 25 | Restage 3 | Target Group 6 |
+====+===========+================+
```

The Custom order of the both columns are to be picked up from 2 single-column Excel ranges (can be
converted to Arrays) as shown below:

**Status1:**

```
+===+================+
|   |       A        |
+===+================+
| 1 | GP             |
+---+----------------+
| 2 | Buyers         |
+---+----------------+
| 3 | Non Buyers     |
+---+----------------+
| 4 | Target Group 1 |
+---+----------------+
| 5 | Target Group 2 |
+---+----------------+
| 6 | Target Group 3 |
+---+----------------+
| 7 | Target Group 4 |
+---+----------------+
| 8 | Target Group 5 |
+---+----------------+
| 9 | Target Group 6 |
+===+================+
```

and :

**Status2:**

```
+====+============+
|    |     A      |
+====+============+
| 1  | Current    |
+----+------------+
| 2  | Restage 1  |
+----+------------+
| 3  | Restage 2  |
+----+------------+
| 4  | Restage 3  |
+----+------------+
| 5  | Restage 4  |
+----+------------+
| 6  | Restage 5  |
+----+------------+
| 7  | Restage 6  |
+----+------------+
| 8  | Restage 7  |
+----+------------+
| 9  | Restage 8  |
+----+------------+
| 10 | Restage 9  |
+----+------------+
| 11 | Restage 10 |
+====+============+
```

For example, :

```
Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
....
With oRS
  .Sort = "Groups <customorder>,Types <customorder>"
End With
```

Does anyone knows how to do a Custom Order sort using a Recordset object?

EDIT:

@CDP1802 thanks for your reply! It works, but i overlooked something that i have to edit my post. Hope you can figure out how to handle it.

Initially the A.[Groups] column in the Base table is blank and I am updating it in the recordset based on values from another column [segment]. So the sorting is coming all wrong!

Here is a main snapshot of the code for your inspection:

```
' Grab `Groups` Filters from Study Details
With shtStudyDetails
  xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  If xLastRow <= 18 Then Exit Sub
  
  ' first check if `Assign` column has been filled in too
  Set xRg = .Range(.Cells(19, "B"), .Cells(xLastRow, "B"))
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(xRg.Offset(0, 1).Cells) < WorksheetFunction.CountA(xRg.Cells) Then Exit Sub
  
  Set sRg = xRg.Resize(xRg.Rows.Count, 2)
  vArr = sRg.Value2
  
  ' Get Segment values excluding `Assign : Not Assigned`
  xStr = ""
  For j = 1 To UBound(vArr)
    If Not InStr(1, vArr(j, 2), "Not Assigned", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then xStr = xStr & "_" & j
  Next j
  If xStr = "" Then
    vIncludeArr = vArr
  Else
    vIncludeArr = Application.Index(vArr, Application.Transpose(Split(Mid(xStr, 2), "_")), Application.Transpose([row(1:2)]))
  End If
  If UBound(vIncludeArr) <= 1 And vIncludeArr(UBound(vIncludeArr), 1) = vbEmpty Then Exit Sub
    
  
  Set KeyValues1 = shtStudyDetails.Cells.Range("E45:F55") ' range1 table on whose values order to sort Groups
  Set KeyValues2 = shtStudyDetails.Cells.Range("G45:H106") ' range2 table on whose values order to sort Type

End With



With shtSummaryOfData
    xLastColumn = .Range("1:1").Cells(.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If xLastColumn = 1 Then Exit Sub

    Set xRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, xLastColumn))
    
    ' clear Summary of data sheet
    xLastRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If xLastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(xLastRow, xLastColumn)).ClearContents

    strSQL = ""
    xStr = ""
    strSQL = "SELECT "
    
    For Each xCell In xRng
      With xCell
          xStr = xCell.Value2
          If InStr(1, xStr, " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then xStr = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xStr, " ", " ")
          If InStr(1, xStr, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then xStr = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xStr, ".", "#")
      End With
      strSQL = strSQL & "A.[" & xStr & "],"
      
    Next xCell

    strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 1)
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM (([" & shtPasteData.Name & "$" & xRg.Address(False, False, xlA1) & "] AS A "
    
    strSQL = strSQL & " LEFT JOIN [" & shtStudyDetails.Name & "$" & KeyValues1.Address(False, False, xlA1) & "] AS G ON G.[Groups] = A.[Groups])"
    strSQL = strSQL & " LEFT JOIN [" & shtStudyDetails.Name & "$" & KeyValues2.Address(False, False, xlA1) & "] AS T ON T.[Type] = A.[Type])"
    
    ' Join Segments in `vIncludeArr` that did not have Assign:Not Assigned
    With Application
      xStr = "'" & Join(.Transpose(.Index(vIncludeArr, 0, 1)), "','") & "'"
    End With
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE A.[segment] IN (" & xStr & ")"
    
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY G.ITEM, T.ITEM "

End With


Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With oCon
    .Mode = adModeReadWrite
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open Join$(Array("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & _
    sPath$ & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;IMEX=0"";"), vbNullString)
End With

With oRec
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    Set .ActiveConnection = oCon
    .Open (strSQL)
    
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    
    ' updating Groups column based on values in `vIncludeArr`
    Do While Not .EOF
        For j = 1 To UBound(vIncludeArr, 1)
          If .Fields("segment").Value = vIncludeArr(j, 1) Then .Fields("Groups").Value = vIncludeArr(j, 2)
        Next j
      .MoveNext
    Loop
  
  .MoveLast
  .MoveFirst
'  .Sort = .Fields("Groups").Name & " ASC," & .Fields("Type").Name & " ASC"
  
  .MoveLast
  .MoveFirst
  shtSummaryOfData.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset .DataSource
  .Close
End With
```

And here is the Unique Segments Table which is used to populate the Blank `Groups` column with the Assigned Groups based on the unique Segment names:

```
╔══════════════════════╤════════════════╗
║ Segments             │ Assign Groups  ║
╠══════════════════════╪════════════════╣
║ ALL RESPONSES        │ GP             ║
╟──────────────────────┼────────────────╢
║ Some xx Target Group │ Target Group 1 ║
╟──────────────────────┼────────────────╢
║ Some Buyer1          │ Buyers         ║
╟──────────────────────┼────────────────╢
║ Some Non-Buyer1      │ Target Group 2 ║
╟──────────────────────┼────────────────╢
║ Some yy Target Group │ Target Group 3 ║
╟──────────────────────┼────────────────╢
║ Some zz Target Group │ Target Group 5 ║
╚══════════════════════╧════════════════╝
```

Comment: You should add an ID to the group and type tables, join them to  base table in your sql statement and then sort on their IDs

Comment: Can you share an example on how it is to be done? I think what you are meaning is not related to the `recordset. Sort` but the SQL query itself. How do I do a join of the main query with the 2 ranges?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes. write a sql query for recordset, that fills the groups column, and also sorts on custom order (as already doing with JOINS), and finally dump the created recordset data to worksheet.

Comment: Its actually a final report `SummaryofData` sheet that will be updated from this Recordset based on csv data pasted in another sheet. The PastedData sheet does not have `Groups` column initially, so i have to add it as last column thru code, then create a recordset from it and update the summarydata sheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239452/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-sifar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an Item column to the 2 custom order tables then join them to the data table and use the Item fields in the sort orders.

[image: Sheet2] [image: Sheet3]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

   Dim con As ADODB.Connection, sCon As String
   sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';"

   Set con = New ADODB.Connection
   With con
      .ConnectionString = sCon
      .Open
   End With
   
   Const SQL = " SELECT A.Type, A.Groups FROM (([Sheet1$] AS A" & _
               " LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] AS T ON T.Type   = A.Type)" & _
               " LEFT JOIN [Sheet3$] AS G ON G.Groups = A.Groups)" & _
               " ORDER BY G.Item, T.Item"
               
   With Sheet4
       .Cells.Clear
       .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset con.Execute(SQL)
   End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: i have updated my post. I overlooked something because of which the sort is not happening correctly. Hope you can help figure out how to do it in SQL itself without resorting to `updating` the Recordset field later.

Comment: This is just awesome! Impressive. Small clean, code, but such great impact! A BIG THANK YOU. I have yet to go through your written SQL Query, but i like your coding style. Once again a BIG THANK YOU! :)